# Switching layout location when outputing data in fragmentShader

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, fbo

I want to use glDrawArraysInstanced function to double triangle.
The difference between the two are MVP matrix.
Then I apply a FBO with 2 GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT, and actived glDrawBuffers(2, ...).

**my vertex shader:**

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView[2];
uniform mat4 uProjection[2];

out flat int ID;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = uProjection[gl_InstanceID] * uView[gl_InstanceID] * uModel * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
    ID = gl_InstanceID;
}
```

**my fragment shader:**

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) out vec3 color;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 color1;

in flat int ID;

void main()
{
    if (ID == 0) color  = vec3(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f);
    if (ID == 1) color1 = vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

The result is:
[4 triangles..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFMHU.png)

It seems that each Instanced had implement the color and color1 statement.
so, is it that the 'if' statement invalid?
And my question is how limite the output target in fbo and during one pass.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot prevent a shader from write into **all** outputs it has attached. What your code does is to **assign** a value just to one output, but the other one is still written.

If you want to get visible output in only one of the attachments, you could for example, write a full transparent color to the output and enable alpha blending.

Comment: Note that, if the ID were a uniform rather than an input, you could use write masks to turn off writes to those particular buffers.

Comment: A new question....As you say,if the shader will write into all outputs, the left and the right will no be the same color triangle, and it will be 'orange'  'red' and 'red'  'orange'.So, is the 'if' statement invalid?